# Why elements of snake don't follow each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've just started learning Unity, and I wanted to try to write a Snake.

Logic goes as follows:

- Head marks its spot
- Head moves
- Loop starts
- - Child goes to marked spot
- - Spot where child was gets marked

This should have made elements of the snake follow each other,  however, it results in weird shapes:
[Here's snake's starting position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QFVV.png)

[And here is snake's position after pressing "w"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNh52.png)

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    int fps = 60;
    Vector3 prev_pos, mark_pos;
    void Start()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = fps;
    }

    void Update_child()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            prev_pos = child.position;
            child.position = mark_pos;
            mark_pos = prev_pos;
            print(child.position);
            print(child.name);
        }   
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mark_pos = transform.position;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))  
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
    }

    
}
```

I firstly want to understand the mistake, not to get the fixed version of the code, if someone could explain the error, I would appreciate it.

I tried doing this with relative and absolute postions, as both of them are used, but to no avail.

Comment: Your issue may come from you not blocking the snake from turning back on itself. Also, please post your logs and a screenshot of your issue so we can visualize it better.

Comment: There, i've added screenshots. Which logs exactly should I post?

Comment: Ah, I see your issue, your tail is a child of your head which means they move whenever your head moves. I will post a detailed solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer was almost correct but in your hierarchy you make the tail a children of the head and in Unity, when you move a parent, all of the children move too. To fix your issue, uncouple the tail and track the transforms.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    int fps = 60;
    Vector3 prev_pos, mark_pos;

    [Header("The head of the snake")]
    [SerializeField] Transform headTransform;
    [Header("The tail of the snake")]
    [SerializeField] Transform[] transforms;

    void Start()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = fps;
    }

    void Update_child()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transforms)
        {
            prev_pos = child.position;
            child.position = mark_pos;
            mark_pos = prev_pos;
            print(child.position);
            print(child.name);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mark_pos = headTransform.position;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            headTransform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            headTransform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {
            headTransform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            headTransform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            Update_child();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example in action]